# Cordova Emulation Bug

Tags: java, android, cordova

I launch the cordova app in the emulator

```
cordova emulate android
```

After running this command, the emulator starts, but the program in the emulator does not start

Instead, I terminal I see this:

```
No emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus_7_2012_API_26
Waiting for emulator to start...
emulator: Requested console port 5584: Inferring adb port 5585.
path /home/$USER/.android/avd/Nexus_7_2012_API_26.avd/system.img.qcow2
path /home/$USER/.android/avd/Nexus_7_2012_API_26.avd/vendor.img.qcow2
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000028
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 000000000000002c
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000028
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 000000000000002c
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 000000000000001c
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000020
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000024
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000020
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 000000000000001c
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000020
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000024
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000028
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 000000000000002c
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 000000000000001c
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000020
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000024
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 000000000000001c
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000024
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000020
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 000000000000002c
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000028
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 000000000000001c
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000024
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000020
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 000000000000002c
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000028
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 000000000000001c
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000024
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000020
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 000000000000002c
qemu-system-i386: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset 0000000000000028
Waiting for emulator to boot (this may take a while).................
```

how do I configure the environment to work with Cordova. Thank you.

Ubuntu 16.04
Cordova 7.1.0

java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be an emulator problem. have you tried using an other emulator instead? I prefer the emulators that come with Android Studio. They are pretty easy to configure and run stable. When you want to test your cordova app, the difference is that you should run the emulator first and then call `cordova run android` instead of `cordova emulate android`

EDIT: [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html) is the official tutorial for creating virtual devices with android studio

Comment: The problem was related to the version of the android emulator. This problem I saw on emulators with version 22 +. On the version below, everything is fine. Many thanks for your answer. Have a nice day and good code)